# How to de-indent chunk of code quickly?

Tags: netbeans, ide, code-formatting

How to do the opposit of indenting chunk of code in Netbeans?

Indenting multiple lines of code, I can select and use Tab key to achieve.

How can I do the reverse of this quickly, not by doing it line by line?

Even better, is there a way to format all the code? Somewhere I used in Dreamweaver before..

Answer (score 23, accepted):

to format all the code in NetBeans, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

If you want to indent lines, select the lines and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>right arrow key</kbd>

and to unindent, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>left arrow key</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> should unindent the current line if none is selected, or multiple lines if they are.

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> will get NB to format highlighted code.

Answer (score 0):

Open "Tools" -> "Options" -> "Keymap", then look for the action called "Re-indent Current Line or Selection" and set whatever shortcut you want.